# Error two clicks to be able to login Angular 16

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, jwt, frontend

When trying to log in, I need to click twice, when I click the first time it doesn't work, when I click the second time it works, I'm not sure if that's it but I'm getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') and I don't know how to solve it, I already put a console.log() in the submitLogin() function and it says that the user does not have a defined name

Component HTML:

```
<div class="center-container">
  <ng-template #loadingPage>
    <div *ngIf="!firstLoad">
      <div class="flex justify-content-center">
        <mat-progress-bar style="max-width: 400px;margin:10px" mode="indeterminate" color="primary"></mat-progress-bar>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <mat-card class="login-card" >
    <mat-card-header>
      <div class="mt-4 text-center">
        <img mat-card-image class="align-items-center"  ngSrc="assets/main-logo.png" width="300" height="70" >
        
      </div>
      
    </mat-card-header>
    
    <mat-card-content>
      <form class="flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center mt-2 mb-4" [formGroup]="loginForm">
        <div class="grid-form-login">
          <mat-form-field class="input-form-login">
            <mat-label>Login</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="identifier">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field class="input-form-login">
            <mat-label>Senha</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password">
          </mat-form-field>
          <div class="flex justify-content-left">
            <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [checked]="rememberMe" [disabled]="loading" (click)="changeRememberMe()">Manter-se conectado</mat-checkbox>
          </div>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" style="width: 100%;" [disabled]="loading" (click)="submitLogin()">Entrar</button>&nbsp;
          <button mat-raised-button color="basic" style="width: 100%;" [disabled]="loading" (click)="loginWithGoogle()">
            Login com o google <mat-icon svgIcon="google" aria-hidden="false" ></mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-footer>
      <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"  *ngIf="loading"></mat-progress-bar>
    </mat-card-footer>
  </mat-card>
</div>

<p-toast></p-toast>
```

My component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user/user.service';
import { DomSanitizer, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LoadingService } from '../../services/loading/loading.service';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { Ilogin } from 'src/app/interfaces/login';

const GOOGLE_ICON =
  `
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <svg width="36px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 36 36" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <!-- Generator: Sketch 43.2 (39069) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
      <title>UI/icons/color/google</title>
      <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
      <defs/>
      <g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="UI/icons/color/google">
              <g id="Group" transform="translate(2.000000, 2.000000)">
                  <path d="M32.4365525,16.6024012 C32.4365525,15.4515967 32.3313665,14.344128 32.1357206,13.2820585 L16.5492615,13.2820585 L16.5492615,19.5616128 L25.4557094,19.5616128 C25.0721312,21.5908257 23.9059692,23.3098098 22.1535707,24.4613022 L22.1535707,28.5341733 L27.5019274,28.5341733 C30.631561,25.7077204 32.4365525,21.5461142 32.4365525,16.6024012 L32.4365525,16.6024012 Z" id="Shape" fill="#4285F4"/>
                  <path d="M16.5492615,32.4674071 C21.0175621,32.4674071 24.7635856,31.0139403 27.5019274,28.5341733 L22.1535707,24.4613022 C20.6718508,25.4353244 18.7756982,26.0110706 16.5492615,26.0110706 C12.2387399,26.0110706 8.59088994,23.1557272 7.2893887,19.3181072 L1.76011213,19.3181072 L1.76011213,23.5244249 C4.48302664,28.8299569 10.0796222,32.4674071 16.5492615,32.4674071 L16.5492615,32.4674071 Z" id="Shape" fill="#34A853"/>
                  <path d="M7.2893887,19.3181072 C6.95840347,18.344085 6.77047118,17.3033395 6.77047118,16.2337035 C6.77047118,15.1640676 6.95840347,14.1233221 7.2893887,13.1492999 L7.2893887,8.94298219 L1.76011213,8.94298219 C0.639530783,11.1345322 0,13.6142992 0,16.2337035 C0,18.8531079 0.639530783,21.3328749 1.76011213,23.5244249 L7.2893887,19.3181072 L7.2893887,19.3181072 Z" id="Shape" fill="#FBBC05"/>
                  <path d="M16.5492615,6.4563365 C18.9790577,6.4563365 21.160615,7.27558824 22.8758478,8.88382548 L27.6225407,4.22764161 C24.755872,1.60892511 21.0098485,0 16.5492615,0 C10.0803235,0 4.48302664,3.63813805 1.76011213,8.94298219 L7.2893887,13.1492999 C8.59088994,9.31236774 12.2394411,6.4563365 16.5492615,6.4563365 Z" id="Shape" fill="#EA4335"/>
              </g>
          </g>
      </g>
  </svg>
`;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  hidePassword: boolean = true;

  loginForm: FormGroup;

  rememberMe: boolean = false;

  firstLoad: boolean = true;

  loading: boolean = false;
  

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private router: Router,
    private titleService: Title,
    public loadingService: LoadingService,
    public iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, 
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    public auth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIconLiteral('google', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(GOOGLE_ICON));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.titleService.setTitle('Login');
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      identifier: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });

    const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.classList.add("bg-default");

  }

  submitLogin() {
    // console.log("CONSOLE.LOG:", this.submitLogin());
    this.firstLoad = false;
    this.loading = true;
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe({
      next: ({jwt, user}: any) => {

        if (user && user.name !== undefined) {
          console.log("Nome do usuario:", user.name);
        } else {
          console.log("usuario Nao possui um nome definido");
        }

        this.rememberMe ? localStorage.setItem('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwt}`) : sessionStorage.setItem('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwt}`);

        localStorage.setItem('schoolId', user.schoolOwner?.id);
        localStorage.setItem('roleName', user.role.name.toLowerCase());

        this.router.navigate(['affiliated-school/list'])
        // this.userService.findMe().subscribe({
        //   next: (user: any) => {
        //     localStorage.setItem('schoolId', user.schoolOwner?.id);
        //     localStorage.setItem('roleName', user.role.name.toLowerCase());
        //     // if(user.affiliatedSchools.length === 1 && user.role.name.toLowerCase() != 'owner')
        //     // localStorage.setItem('affiliatedSchoolId', user.affiliatedSchools[0].id);
        //     user.role.name === 'Owner' || user.role.name === 'Teacher' || user.role.name === 'Manager' || user.role.name === 'Secretary' ? this.router.navigate(['affiliated-school/list']) : this.router.navigate(['school-class/list']);
        //   }
        // });
      },
      error: () => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Erro', detail: 'Usuario ou senha incorreto.' });
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }

  changeRememberMe() {
    this.rememberMe = !this.rememberMe;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.classList.remove("bg-default");
  }

  async loginWithGoogle () {
    this.loading = true;

    await this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      this.loading = false
    })

    const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()

    const payload = {
      token: token,
      provider: 'firebase'
    } as Ilogin

    this.authService.login(payload).subscribe({
      next: ({ jwt, user }: any) => {

        this.rememberMe ? localStorage.setItem('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwt}`) : sessionStorage.setItem('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwt}`);

        localStorage.setItem('schoolId', user.schoolOwner?.id);
        localStorage.setItem('roleName', user.name.toLowerCase());

        this.router.navigate(['affiliated-school/list'])
        // this.userService.findMe().subscribe({
        //   next: (user: any) => {
        //     localStorage.setItem('schoolId', user.schoolOwner?.id);
        //     localStorage.setItem('roleName', user.role.name.toLowerCase());
        //     if(user.role.name === 'Student' || user.role.name === 'Teacher' || user.role.name === 'Parent')
        //       localStorage.setItem('affiliatedSchoolId', user.affiliatedSchool.id);
        //     user.role.name === 'Owner' ? this.router.navigate(['affiliated-school/list']) : this.router.navigate(['school-class/list']);
        //   },
        //   error: (error) => {
        //     console.log(error)
        //     this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Erro', detail: 'Ocorreu um erro ao logar com o google' });
        //   }
        // });
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(error)
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Erro', detail: 'Ocorreu um erro ao logar com o google' });
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    })
  }

}
```

```
login.component.ts:82 
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Object.next (login.component.ts:94:52)
    at ConsumerObserver.next (Subscriber.js:91:33)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:60:26)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at map.js:7:24
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at filter.js:6:128
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
Zone - XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:load (assíncrono)        
submitLogin @   login.component.ts:82
LoginComponent_Template_button_click_21_listener    @   login.component.html:32
Zone - HTMLButtonElement.addEventListener:click (assíncrono)        
LoginComponent_Template @   login.component.html:32
Zone - Promise.then (assíncrono)        
logout  @   auth.service.ts:65
logout  @   toolbar.component.ts:45
ToolbarComponent_Template_button_click_18_listener  @   toolbar.component.html:47
Zone - HTMLButtonElement.addEventListener:click (assíncrono)        
ToolbarComponent_Template   @   toolbar.component.html:47
Promise.then (assíncrono)       
4913    @   main.ts:8
__webpack_exec__    @   main.ts:9
(anônimo)   @   main.ts:9
(anônimo)   @   main.ts:9
(anônimo)
```

I need to know how to set the name property to be sure if this is what causes the problem of two clicks to log in

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared the auth service code, we can simply use `?.` of typescript to null check the user so that will get rid of the console error!

```
  submitLogin() {
    this.firstLoad = false;
    this.loading = true;
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe({
      next: ({jwt, user}: any) => {

        if (user?.name !== undefined) {
          console.log("Nome do usuario:", user.name);
        } else {
          console.log("usuario Nao possui um nome definido");
        }

        this.rememberMe ? localStorage.setItem('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwt}`) : sessionStorage.setItem('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwt}`);

        localStorage.setItem('schoolId', user?.schoolOwner?.id);
        localStorage.setItem('roleName', user?.role?.name?.toLowerCase());

        this.router.navigate(['affiliated-school/list'])
        // this.userService.findMe().subscribe({
        //   next: (user: any) => {
        //     localStorage.setItem('schoolId', user.schoolOwner?.id);
        //     localStorage.setItem('roleName', user.role.name.toLowerCase());
        //     // if(user.affiliatedSchools.length === 1 && user.role.name.toLowerCase() != 'owner')
        //     // localStorage.setItem('affiliatedSchoolId', user.affiliatedSchools[0].id);
        //     user.role.name === 'Owner' || user.role.name === 'Teacher' || user.role.name === 'Manager' || user.role.name === 'Secretary' ? this.router.navigate(['affiliated-school/list']) : this.router.navigate(['school-class/list']);
        //   }
        // });
      },
      error: () => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Erro', detail: 'Usuario ou senha incorreto.' });
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }
```